# Comparing Oracle 10g and Oracle 11g Schema

Tags: oracle10g, oracle11g, database-schema, schema-compare

I have a task at hand wherein we need to compare two database schemas at two different versions.

Actually an application has been upgraded to use Oracle 11g , older version of the application used Oracle 10g. Basically what needs to be checked is the differences in the schemas of the two different versioned applications mainly to check if no functionality is broken or no relevant schema change is missed

I did some R&D and found many tools are available to compare schemas, DB Solo etc. But my requirement being to compare two schemas at 2 different versions. The tools are available to compare schemas at same version.

Some of the solutions I came up with after having discussions with seniors
1) establish a DB link between the 2 DB schemas and do a comparison of USER_OBJECTS. This solution is however not feasible for us.

2) If we can get a TEXT like dump of both the schemas, a basic text comparison would give the schema differences.

However, I do not know how Solution 2 would be possible.
I have seen some older posts like
[Compare two schemas and update the old schema with the new columns of new schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332617/compare-two-schemas-and-update-the-old-schema-with-the-new-columns-of-new-schema) but I need a more simplistic solution!

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you already try "Tools"->"Database Diff" from [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) ?

Comment: Yes I did come across that one..I see Source and Destination Connection being supplied..what I could not understand was..if those connection could be 10g and 11g schema respectively http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52sqldev-1735911.html